# Медиа запрос max-width не работает ниже значения 979px

Tags: css, вёрстка, запрос

Только начал в медиа запросы:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 978px) {
  #adaptive {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Если ставлю меньше чем 979px (!), страница перестает реагировать на правило.
Т.е. я хочу поставить например max-width: 500px, но это не работает, работает от 979+.

Создавал новую страницу - с чистого листа, на один блок - то же самое. хелп

Comment: "Если ставлю меньше чем 979px (!)" - где именно и что именно Вы ставите? Покажите весь ваш код (с html), а лучше сделайте воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так же проверь meta viewport

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Странно, что на ютубе это никто не упоминал.

Answer (score 1):

> Если ставлю меньше чем 979px (!), страница перестает реагировать на
>   правило. Т.е. я хочу поставить например max-width: 500px, но это не
>   работает, работает от 979+.

Страница не может не реагировать на правило. Смотрите пример ниже. Вероятнее всего, где-то у вас ошибка.

```css
#adaptive {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 978px) {
  #adaptive {
    background-color: pink;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #adaptive {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="adaptive"></div>
```